# Erlang: what is this process identifier in the form of {from, Pid, Ref}?

Tags: erlang

I am now facing a problem. when i check the erl_crash.dump, i found some stuff as below:

```
=proc:<0.19275.17>  
State: Scheduled  
Spawned as: proc_lib:init_p/5  
Spawned by: <0.18723.17>  
Started: Wed May 8 13:30:40 2013  
Message queue length: 1  
Number of heap fragments: 0  
Heap fragment data: 0  
Link list: [<0.20051.17>, <0.9976.18>, ..., **{from,<6524.13.0>,#Ref<6524.0.1.37040>}, {from,<6474.13.0>,#Ref<6474.0.1.36682>}, {from,<6470.13.0>,#Ref<6470.0.1.34219>}**, ...]
```

there is something like **{from, Pid, Ref}** in the link list of the proc <0.19275.17>.
i have no idea what these weird formed processes identifier are. i guess maybe it is related to "process monitoring". am i right? and i still want to know how can i generate such a process identifier and how can i make use of them ?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that the process was monitored by other processes. From documentation:

> If process monitoring is used, this field also tells in which
>   direction the monitoring is in effect, i.e., a link being "to" a
>   process tells you that the "current" process was monitoring the other
>   and a link "from" a process tells you that the other process was
>   monitoring the current one.

You can find more infromation [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/crash_dump.html)

Comment: As links are bidirectional and monitoring is single directional.

Comment: Thank you Kachayew! Then, such form of process identifier can only be seen in erl_crash.dump, right? i can not see them use process_info(), am i right？

Comment: @rHao1116 You can use ``process_info`` function in order to get information about process with given PID.

Comment: As a side note, here is a shell script to analyze crash dumps to extract generally useful information: https://github.com/ferd/erl_crashdump_analyzer

Comment: Thank you guys. I found that this special form of pid is due to monitoring. But it can only be seen in erl_crash.dump. If just process_info(Pid), you will see the normal one.

Answer (score 1):

I think {from,<6524.13.0>,#Ref<6524.0.1.37040>} is that you register a global name,  so global name server is monitoring this process.

more info: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/global.html